# Sonarqube 5.1 TFS sonar msbuild runner with branches

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We have just started using Sonarqube 5.1 integrated in TFS build as described on this page http://www.sonarqube.org/announcing-sonarqube-integration-with-msbuild-and-team-build/

We have one main branch, and two development branches for the same project. 
What is the recommended strategy for handling this?
I want to be able to see analyze result trends over time and also let people working in different branches able to see analyze result for the branch they are working in. As far as I can see the Sonar msbuild runner (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-msbuild-runner) only supports projectkey, projectname and version, but not branch key.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed Wangen, I do confirm that the MSBuild Runner 0.9 doesn't yet provide a way to inject some SonarQube properties and so including the "sonar.branch" property. This limitation is going to be dropped in version 1.0 of the MSBuild Runner. Nevertheless, you must be aware that the support of branches by SonarQube is really limited because at the end in your case you're going to have 3 different projects in SonarQube and for instance flagging an issue as false-positive won't lead to flag the same issue in another branch as false-positive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, so then I'm able to achieve the same result without the branch flag then, if I name the projectname differently in each build on the TFS.